# Realtek HD audio manager not starting

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers

I suddenly noticed only my left speaker was working. So I tried sound trouble shooting and I believe I opted to use windows default sound driver and the realtek program closed.

Now I figured my right speaker is working on very low volume and want to get the Realtek manager again. But clicking on it in the control panel won't open it.

At the moment I just want my old setup back with the Realtek audio manager but I cannot find any option how to do that. If I run the troubleshooter again it does not give me the option to switch back. So once again I fell in the trap of MS auto trouble shooting that automatically disables things and therefor not knowing how to re-enable these.